# Binary Search Tree: Recursive toString

Tags: java, recursion, binary-tree

It only prints out one item.
It is suppose to print the contents of the tree in ascending order

```
public String toString()
{
    return toString (_root);
}
private String toString(BSTnode root)
{
    if (root == null)
        return "";
    toString(root._left);
    toString(root._right);
    return root._data.toString();
}
```

Answer (score 4):

How do you want to show them?

You need to append the Strings, for example.

```
private String toString(BSTnode root)
{
    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
    if (root == null)
        return "";
    builder.append(toString(root._left));
    builder.append(toString(root._right));
    return builder.append(root._data.toString()).toString();
}
```

or just use a concatenation on strings.

```
private String toString(BSTnode root)
{
    String result = "";
    if (root == null)
        return "";
    result += toString(root._left);
    result += toString(root._right);
    result += root._data.toString()
    return result;
}
```

Comment: How would I go about adding a comma after each char in the string? i.e. "a,b,c,d,e,f"

Answer (score 0):

```
//Helper

public String toString(){
return "<" +toString(root) + ">";
}

//recursively printing out the nodes

public static String toString(Node r){
if(r==null)
return "";
else
return toString(r.left) + " " +r.value + " " +toString(r.right);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public class TreeNode {
    int val;
    TreeNode left;
    TreeNode right;

    TreeNode(int x) {
        val = x;
    }

    // Helper

    public String toString() {
        return "<" + toString(this) + ">";
    }

    // recursively printing out the nodes

    public static String toString(TreeNode r) {
        if (r == null)
            return "";
        else
            return r.val + " " + toString(r.left) + " " + toString(r.right);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public String toString(){
    return toString (_root);
}

public String toStringAscending(BSTnode node)
{
    if (node == null) return "";
    return toStringAscending(node.left) + node._data.toString() + toStringAscending(node.right);
}
```